# check of business is open or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, time, trading

I am trying to check the day and hours of a business to determine if its open or not.

I have this code in my supplier partial

```
%li
  = link_to shopping_supplier_path(supplier) do
    = content_tag :div, class: 'grid-block' do
      = content_tag :div, supplier.image_available, :class => 'small-3 grid-content'
      = content_tag :div, :class => 'small-9 grid-content' do
        %h4= supplier.name.truncate(30).titlecase
        = content_tag :div, class: 'grid-block' do
          .small-3.grid-content 9/10
          .small-3.grid-content $$
          .small-6.grid-content.text-right
            - SupplierTradingHour.open.includes(:supplier).each do |hour|
              = "#{hour.supplier.name} is open! It closes at #{hour.close_time}."
```

TradingHour Model

```
class SupplierTradingHour < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supplier

  scope :open, lambda { |day, time| { :conditions => ["self.weekday = ? AND self.open_time >= ? AND self.close_time < ?", day, time, time] } }

end
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What's happening? It's not behaving as expected?

Comment: ArgumentError at /shopping/suppliers
wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `open` scope without arguments: `SupplierTradingHour.open` but your `:open` scope is a lambda expression with two arguments `|day, time|` which one of the reasons why your code is failing.

Your SQL logical expression is also not correct: `open_time <= ? AND close_time > ?` (note the operators are the opposite of yours)

In your case, for a DIY implementation (without using third party gems) I would suggest doing this:

```
#app/models/trading_hour.rb
class TradingHour < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :supplier

  scope :open_now, -> (day, time) { where("weekday = ? AND open_time <= ? AND close_time > ?", day, time, time) }

end
```

then in your supplier model:

```
#app/models/supplier.rb
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :trading_hours

  def opening_status day, hour
    today_trading_hours = trading_hours.open_now(day, hour)
    if today_trading_hours.size > 0
      "Opened until #{today_trading_hours.first.close_time}H"
    else
      "Closed" 
    end 
  end
end
```

Then from your view call

```
#if today is day 1
#and current hour is 12
supplier.opening_status(1, 12)
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to return the correct sql as the merchant_id is being set to nil `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trading_hours" WHERE "trading_hours"."merchant_id" = $1 AND (weekday = 0 AND open_time <= '2016-05-29 03:01:59.377064' AND close_time > '2016-05-29 03:01:59.377064')  [["merchant_id", nil]]`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative implementation, you might want to consider using the following gem for business hour related functionalities:

https://github.com/Intrepidd/working_hours

Comment: this is no good as i have multiple hours across different suppliers

Answer (score 0):

setting a scope is fine but I would probably just define my `@suppliers` with something like:

```
@suppliers = Supplier.where("weekday = ? AND open_time > ? AND closing_time < ?", day, time, time)
```

Another option, if you need both sides of it in different circumstances, would be to write an instance method `is_open?`

Comment: doing this an adding the method, all i get is that the business is closed, do i need to datetruc the current time?